# PC Shutdowns when playing games with wine

Tags: wine, games

Whenever I play/run games with wine, my pc shuts down, and when I start it up again it shuts down again. ¿what can I do?

Comment: Not likely to be wine related. Probably hardware, overheating because the symptom persists if booted immediately after the fact. This question is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Your description suggests a hardware fault. Ubuntu does not have a "sutdown without warning" feature (who would want that?)...but your motherboard does.

The two most common causes of sudden shutdowns are:

1. Overheating
2. Failing power supply.

There are other possible hardware-related causes.

Use your favorite Search Engine to look up hardware diagnostic techniques to narrow down the possible causes and how to fix each one.

We wish you good luck fixing your hardware.